# popd for cdr-based directory management in zsh

Tags: zsh, interactive, working-directory

I recently started using [`cdr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#cdr) in `zsh` for remembering recent directories.  I used to use `pushd` and the like.  One thing I miss is `popd`, which basically means "I'm done using this directory, put me back where I used to be and get rid of this entry in the stack."

Can a similar semantic be done with `cdr`?

*Edit: change "history" to "stack".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type

```sh
cdr -p $PWD
```

and `cdr` will *prune* the directory you're in from its list. To prune another directory, just replace `$PWD` with the absolute path name of the dir you want to remove. Or if you want to remove a whole set of dirs, you can also use glob patterns in the argument. And before `cdr -p` makes any changes, it will show you what the results of your action will be and will ask you to confirm, so you don't have to worry about "accidentally the whole thing". See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Options-2 for more info.

To go back to the previous dir you we're in, do

```sh
cd -
```

You can combine both of these in a function:

```sh
cdpop() {
  local dir=$PWD

  # `cdr` without arguments does the same `cdr 1`: Go back to the previous 
  # dir.
  cdr

  # `-P` does the same as `-p`, but is silent and doesn't ask for 
  # confirmation.
  cdr -P $dir
}
```

By the way: You can set up `cdr` to also do `cd` commands. To enable this, put the following into your `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
zstyle ':chpwd:*' recent-dirs-default true
```

Then, any argument you pass to `cdr` that is not specific to `cdr` will be passed to `cd` instead. Then you don't need to think about whether to use `cd` or `cdr`; you can just always use `cdr` for everything. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Configuration-2 for more info.

> One thing I miss is `popd`, which basically means "I'm done using this directory, put me back where I used to be and get rid of this entry in the history."

Small correction: `popd` doesn't remove a dir from *history*, it removes it from the *directory stack*.

Comment: This ends up failing when the previous directory (from `cd -`) isn't in the `cdr` list, adding it back to the list.  I ended up modifying it to be `cdpop() { local dir="$PWD"; cdr; cdr -P $dir; }`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that behavior. I updated my answer.